# Create a function that returns all slices of a vector that are one length less than previous function call

Tags: clojure

For example,

```
(def sample-arr [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9])

(defn create-func [arr]
;; Code goes here)

(def result-function (create-func sample-arr))

(result-function) => [7, 5, 8, 11, 9], [10, 7, 5, 8, 11]
(result-function) => [7, 5, 8, 9], [10, 7, 5, 8], etc
(result-function) => {all subarays of length 2}
```

History: I'm learning Clojure, and I created the problem myself to get a better understanding of how closures work in Closure. With everything immutable I'm unable to figure out how to store state inside a closure that I would write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very un-idiomatic to make functions that retain state in such a way in clojure, and more generally in functional-style programming. Functional Programming is usually about keeping your functions "[referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)", which could simply be put as "the function will always return the same value for the same input" (and thus one could replace the function call with its return value). Your function obviously is not referentially transparent, as it will return a different value based on call history rather than on its input arguments alone (which it does not take any). As you experianced, this is harder to achieve using immutable data-structures.

A more FP-style approach would be to make function that constructs a "lazy" list such that each item in the list will be the result of one of your proposed consecutive calls:

```
(defn all-subs [input-arr]
  (map (fn[length] (partition length 1 input-arr)) (reverse (range 1 (count input-arr)))))
```

With this you get:

```
(def result (all-subs [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9]))

(first result)
=> ((10 7 5 8 11) (7 5 8 11 9))

(second result)
=> ((10 7 5 8) (7 5 8 11) (5 8 11 9))

(nth result 3)
=>((10 7) (7 5) (5 8) (8 11) (11 9))
```

This way you get to use only immutable structure, be referentially transparent, and even support lazy computation! Win!

Comment: With reverse and count, this is not very lazy.

Comment: True amalloy, reverse should be used on the 'range', and 'count' only realizes the input seq, not the result. Changing the answer

Answer (score 0):

as an exercise i would go with something like that:

```
(defn all-partitions
  ([items] (all-partitions items (count items)))
  ([items n] (with-meta (partition n 1 items) 
                        {:next #(all-partitions items (dec n))})))
```

the call to this function returns partitions, and metadata for this result holds the function partitioning the same collection, but with one less item in group:

```
(def res (all-partitions [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]))

(println res)
;;=> ((1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

(def res2 ((-> res meta :next)))

(println res2)
;;=> ((1 2 3 4 5 6) (2 3 4 5 6 7))

(def res3 ((-> res2 meta :next)))

(println res3)
;;=> ((1 2 3 4 5) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6 7))
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mutable version using atoms and protocols+records just for fun :

```
 (def n (atom 0))
 (def init-len (atom 0))
 (def final-result (atom nil))

 (defprotocol StateFunction
   (init [this])
   (iter [this])
   (reset [this]))

 (defrecord ResultFunction [coll]
   StateFunction
   (init [this]
         (let [len (count coll)]
           (do (reset! n len)
               (reset! init-len len)
               (reset! bcoll coll))))
   (iter [this]
         (let [delta (inc (- @init-len @n))]
           (if (nil? @final-result)
             (loop [base coll
                    result '()
                    i 0]
               (cond (>= i delta)
                       (let [_  (swap! n dec)
                             _ (if (zero? @n) (reset! final-result result))]
                         result)
                     :else
                       (recur (rest base) (conj result (take @n base)) (inc i))))
             @final-result)))
   (reset [this]
          (do (reset! n 0) (reset! init-len 0) (reset! bcoll []) (reset! final-result nil))))

 (defn create-func [coll]
   (let [my-fun (map->ResultFunction {:coll coll})]
     (init my-fun)
     my-fun))

 (def my-fun (create-func [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]))
 (iter my-fun) ;; gives next list of partitions, result at n = 1 is stored to avoir redo
 (reset my-fun) ;; resets atoms, you can next init them to restart the cycle
```

I hope it is possible to wrap it in a way that we can have multiple instances of it (local atoms inside records) though you can return updated record